# Cython package with __init__.pyx: Possible?

Tags: python, python-2.7, cython, python-import, python-c-extension

Is it possible to create a Python 2.7 package using `__init__.pyx` (compiled to `__init__.so`)?  If so how?  I haven't had any luck getting it to work.

Here is what I have tried:

- `setup.py`:

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/env python

  from distutils.core import setup
  from distutils.extension import Extension
  from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

  foo = Extension(name='foo.__init__', sources=['foo/__init__.pyx'])
  bar = Extension(name='foo.bar', sources=['foo/bar.pyx'])

  setup(name='foo',
        packages = ['foo'],
        cmdclass={'build_ext':build_ext},
        ext_modules = [foo, bar])
  ```
- `foo/__init__.pyx`:

  ```
  import foo.bar

  cpdef hello_world():
      print "hello world"
      foo.bar.blah()
  ```
- `foo/bar.pyx`:

  ```
  cpdef blah():
      print "blah"
  ```

The above has the following behavior:

```
$ python -c 'import foo; foo.hello_world()'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named foo
```

I saw [Python issue #15576](http://bugs.python.org/issue15576) which was fixed by [this Hg commit](https://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/1db6553f3f8c).  Looking at the [equivalent Git commit](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/83d1e4996b10951e2c6660de360095362a210a9b) in the [Git mirror](https://github.com/python/cpython) of the Python Hg repository, I see that the commit is reachable from the Python v2.7.5 tag (as well as all subsequent v2.7.x versions).  Was there a regression?

Comment: Just out of curiousity: Why should you do that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to [this really old mailing list post](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2008-October/002292.html) it works if you also have an `__init__.py` file (the `__init__.py` file is not used, but seems to be necessary for the directory to be treated as a module, and hence the `__init__.so` file to be loaded).

If I add `__init__.py`:

```
# an exception just to confirm that the .so file is loaded instead of the .py file
raise ImportError("__init__.py loaded when __init__.so should have been loaded")
```

then your example works on Linux Python 2.7.3:

```
$ python -c 'import foo; foo.hello_world()'
hello world
blah
```

This has all the signs of a buggy corner case so probably isn't recommended. Note that on Windows this doesn't seem to work for me giving

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

---

**Addendum** (for a little extra context):

This behaviour doesn't seem to be explicitly documented. In [the original description of packages](http://legacy.python.org/doc/essays/packages.html) from around Python 1.5 era they say:

> without the `__init__.py`, a directory is not recognized as a package

and

> Tip: the search order is determined by the list of suffixes returned by the function `imp.get_suffixes()`. Usually the suffixes are searched in the following order: ".so", "module.so", ".py", ".pyc". Directories don't explicitly occur in this list, but precede all entries in it.

The observed behaviour is certainly consistent with this — `__init__.py` needed to treat a directory as a package, but .so file is loaded in preference to .py file — but it's hardly unambiguous.

From a Cython point of view this behaviour seems to be been used to compile the standard library (in which case `__init__.py` would always have been present), or in the testcases given https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/master/tests/build/package_compilation.srctree (and a few other examples too). In these the "srctree" file looks to be expanded into a variety of folders containing `__init__.py` (and other files) then compiled. It's possible that only having `__init__.so` was simply never tested.

Comment: Is this trick mentioned in the official documentation?  (it apparently wasn't at the time of that mailing list thread, but maybe things have changed since then)

Comment: I don't think so. (I found it by accident and then came across the newsgroup post slightly after and realised what I'd done.) I'll have a little look and update my answer if I can find a better source. It also works with an `__init__.pyc` file too, it seems.

Comment: Suggestions for improvement:  Rather than `assert False`, raising an `ImportError` might be better.  Or maybe there's some low-level stuff that can be done with the `imp` module as a fall-back in case this trick stops working in a future version of Python.

Comment: @RichardHansen I've updated it to raise ImportError (I agree - it's clearly better!) and added a link to the little documentation I can find that supports it. I think it's basically undocumented

Answer (score -3):

Try using a relative import.

in `__init__`:

`from . import bar`

Might also be `from . import foo`. Haven't used python 2 cython in a while.