# Porting a Simple Python module to Cython

Tags: python, cython, distutils

Let's say I have a directory "pylib" with this in it:

pylab/funcs.py:

```
def add(a, b):
    return a + b
```

pylab/__init__.py:

```
from .funcs import add
```

It is then possible to do the following:

```
$ python -c "import pylib as lib; print(lib.add(5, 6))"
11
```

**How can I achieve the same effect with Cython with a similar organizational structure?** That is, if I just have a single file, like:

cylab.pyx:

```
def add(a, b):
    return a + b
```

I can create a setup script

setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

extensions = [ # I will eventually be referencing C libraries
    Extension('cylib', ['cylib.pyx'], libraries=[], library_dirs=[])
]

setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize(extensions)
)
```

and then the rest works in a fairly straightforward way

```
$ ./setup.py build_ext --inplace
[omitted]
$ python -c "import cylib as lib; print(lib.add(5, 6))"
11
```

but it is not clear to me how I'm supposed to break it up into separate files, nor how I'm supposed to modify the setup script once I do.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really possible to build a single Cython extension containing submodules. I think your best option is to build lots of individual Cython libraries.

Just rename all your .py to .pyx to generate a bunch of Cython extensions. The structure will be the same as it was before. I'd exclude the module `__init__.py` and keep that as pure Python (the rules for how Python finds modules in this case [are a little more complicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28261147/cython-package-with-init-pyx-possible/32067984#32067984).

You want to list all of your .pyx files as separate extensions in setup.py:

```
extensions = [ # I will eventually be referencing C libraries
    Extension('cylib.funcs', ['cylib/funcs.pyx'], libraries=[], library_dirs=[]),
    Extension('cylib.something_else', ['cylib/something_else.pyx'], libraries=[], library_dirs=[])
]
```

(and probably also tell `setup.py` that the whole `cylib` directory is a package, as you would when using `distutils`/`setuptools` with similar pure Python modules.)